# Which permission should be added to add contact?

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to add a new contact in android phone.
For that I am using following code.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID, "jadeja");
                values.put(Phone.NUMBER, 1234567890);
                values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Phone.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

But it force closes the application and inside "LogCat" it shows that security permission denial.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to the AndroidManifest.XML file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be added in manifest 
[WRITE_CONTACTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_CONTACTS)

Answer (score 1):

Add these permissions in android `Maifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />       
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```